Receiving a Firebase Exception When Using AppCheck: no appcheckprovider installed
I'm using Firebase's AppCheck in my Unity game. Right now I am developing for iOS and have decided to use App Attest as my attestation provider. Since the service that I'm authenticating with is a custom backend service, I am following Firebase's documentation on creating the token on the client side in that particular scenario: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/unity/default-providers#ios+. I'm creating the app attest provider instance and then passing the instance into the provider factory like this:
void Awake()
{
    Auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    AnonAuth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    AppAttestProviderFactory.Instance.CreateProvider(Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance);
    FirebaseAppCheck.SetAppCheckProviderFactory(AppAttestProviderFactory.Instance);
}

Later in the code I pass the default app check instance into our email service function so that we can call its GetAppCheckTokenAsync functionality.
public async Task SendEmailVerificationAsync(User user, FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck)
{
    var appCheckToken = await GetAppCheckTokenAsync(firebaseAppCheck);
    var jsonUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    //Other stuff
}

My code freezes on the GetAppCheckTokenAsync call, and during my debugging of the issue I saw that I received the inner exception: firebase.firebaseexception: no appcheckprovider installed. I figured that because I was running the code in the Unity editor that that was the original reason that I had that issue, but building on my iPhone gave the same result. I feel that there's something additional that I need to do on the App Attest side of things and all that I found on the Apple Developer website was to add an app ID for your project, which I've done. Are there any files to be downloaded into my Unity project or configuration that needs to happen in order for the App Attest provider to be recognized?
I feel that there's something additional that I need to do on the App Attest side of things and all that I found on the Apple Developer website was to add an app ID for your project, which I've done, but to no avail. I saw that DeviceCheck needs a private key to be created but saw no such thing for App Attest.
